# Why this piece of code results infinite loop

Tags: c

```
unsigned int i = 1<<10;

for(; i>=0; i--) printf(“%d\n”, i);
```

Can anyone please explain the reason why this code results in infinite loop? Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: what you need is this `for(; i>0; i--)`

Comment: What is the problem with having >= ? I don't want to know how to stop the infinite loop, rather I want to know the reason why the infinite loop is resulting in.

Comment: Others have commented on the cause of the infinite loop, however be aware that you may need to pass the 'u' conversion specifier in your printf statement. printf("%u\n", i);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unsigned integers are always positive. When `i == 0` and you decrement `1` from it, result will wrap-around to maximum `unsigned int` value `UINT_MAX`, because your data type cannot handle negative values.

Answer (score 6):

**Unsigned int** - its always interpreted as >= 0

Answer (score 1):

Reason why it results in an infinite loop is already explained by other answers. However to achieve the intended behaviour of your code, counting down from 1024 to 0 using unsigned int, try this instead.

```
unsigned int i = (1<<10)+1;

for(;i-- > 0;) printf(“%d\n”, i);
```

Note that the value of i after the loop will be the rolled over value.